# JQuery's Change() event don't catch values selected by autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Onchange Event Defined on a Textbox as below

```
 $('input[ComponentAttribute]').on("change",function () {
                dataTxt = "";
                var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
                var temp = $('#' + thisID).val();
                if (!(temp.trim()=='')) {
                    //                    alert($(this).attr('ComponentAttributeID') + " - " + temp);
                    placeholder[$(this).attr('ComponentAttributeID')] = temp;
                    for (var key in placeholder) {
                        if (key === 'length' || !placeholder.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                        var value = placeholder[key];
                        dataTxt += key + ":" + value + ";";
                    }
                    $('[DataAttributeValue]').text(dataTxt);
                }
            });
```

Now, the event fires when user enters value by keyboard. But when user selects a value from Autocomplete as shown, [image]  the Event don't fire. What am I missing here?

Comment: try: $('input[ComponentAttribute]').on('change keyup', function () {

Comment: Testing a simple autocomplete using the console $('#idValue').on("change",function () {alert('hello');}); works, what is your intended value for [ComponentAttribute]?

Comment: Component attribute is used to filter the potential input fields  in the entire form where user can enter value

Comment: right but as a variable what value is it producing at runtime?

Comment: I just use this but dont assign a value for this attribute making it available for filtering input controls

Comment: @Deep` $('input[ComponentAttribute]').on('change keyup', function () {` is not working